# Equivalent to HashSet.Contains that returns HashSet or index?

Tags: c#, string, linq, performance, hashset

I have a large list of emails that I need to check test to see if they contain a string. I only need to do this once. I originally only need to check to see if they email matched any of the emails from a list of emails.

I was using `if(ListOfEmailsToRemoveHashSet.Contains(email)) { Discard(email); }`
This worked great, but now I need to check for partial matches, so I am trying to invert it, but if I used the same method, I would be testing it like...
`if (ListOfEmailsHashSet.Contains(badstring)`. Obviously that tells me which string is being found, but not which index in the hashset contains the bad string.

I can't see any way of making this work while still being fast.

**Does anyone know of a function I can use that will return the HashSet of matches, the index of a matched item, or any way around this?**

Comment: Your questions sounds a bit like you're confusing [String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) and [HashSet.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440.aspx). Can you rephrase your question to make the distinction between these more clear? Maybe provide an example?

Comment: Would it make a difference if I mentioned that the HashSets are HashSet<string>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I only need to do this once.

If this is the case, performance shouldn't really be a consideration. Something like this should work:

```
if(StringsToDisallow.Any(be => email.Contains(be))) {...}
```

On a side note, you may want to consider using Regular Expressions rather than a straight black-list of contained strings. They'll give you a much more powerful, flexible way to find matches.

If performance does turn out to be an issue after all, you'll have to find a data structure that works better for full-text searching. It might be best to leverage an existing tool like [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/).

Comment: I do need to do it a bunch of times, but only once on each list, I have a bunch of lists. I'll try that though. I added once to hopefully stop people from asking me why I am not using a database, which happened in the last question I asked regarding a similar case.

Comment: That seemed to work quite well, and it was faster then I was expecting.

Comment: User error here, its not working. It seems like it would take hours for each list, unless I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Double user error, I was wrong about being wrong. Seems like it was working, too much spaghetti code trying to get this working in time.

Comment: If you don't think it hurts readability, you can even drop the anonymous function and use the named (i.e. non-anonymous) method `Contains` directly, as in `if (StringsToDisallow.Any(email.Contains)) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note here, We had a program that was tasked with uploading excess of 100,000 pdf/excel/doc etc, everytime the file was uploaded an entry was made in a text file. Every Night when the program ran it would read this file, load the records and add it to the `static HashSet<string> FilesVisited = new HashSet<string>(); FilesVisited.Add(reader.ReadLine());`.

When the program attempted to upload a file, we had to first scan through the `HashSet` to see if we already worked on the file. What we found was that
`if (!FilesVisited.Contains(newFilePath))...` would take a lot of time and would not give us the correct results (even if the file path was in there) alternately, `FilesVisited.Any(m => m.Contains(newFilePath))` was also a slow operation.

The best way we found to be fast was the traditional way of

```
foreach (var item in FilesVisited)
   {
     if (item.Contains(fileName)) {
         alreadyUploded = true;
         break;
     }
   }
```

Just thought I would share this....